# Two different data models in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

lets assume that we need two different kind of pages for a UIPageViewController (e.g one that is only text and images, and another one that can be a UIWebView).

If I want lets say pages 1-10 to be of the first data model, and pages 20-30 of the second, is there any way to use two data models? or do I have to use one that covers everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you just return UIViewControllers from the UIPageViewController delegate? Technically you could return as many different UIViewControllers as you want.

Comment: Yes thanks for you help. Turns out there was a mixup by seeing the default code from the Xcode PageView app template. The model of each page doesn't have to do with the rendering that can be done even without a binding model for that page.